# what are the special characters that are not allowed during creation of activemq queue?

Tags: powershell, activemq-classic

what are the special characters that are not allowed during creation of apache activemq queue?I am using the "browse" command of activemq in powershell to create the queues.The console however allows all special characters.I am getting confused that,is it Powershell that has a problem while using special characters or is it activemq itself that restricts the usage of special characters.

Thanks in advance.

C:\Users> activemq-admin browse --amqurl tcp://localhost:61616 sa*R 
But the queue was not created neither error was thrown.

Comment: Can you provide more context, what error do you see, what names are you trying to use etc.

Comment: I did not get any error.